# Reading each paragraph from a file into several lists during run time

Tags: python, file, list

Say I have a file like,

```
ID1


Some name

Address

Salary

Gender


ID2

Some name

Address

Salary

Gender

...

IDn
```

I have read the file , sorted it and appended all the fields into a list like

```
[ID1 , name,Address,Salary,Gender,ID2,name,Address,Salart,Gender..]
```

What i need is , a list say

```
ID1= [name,address,Salary,Gender] ,
ID2 = [name,Address,salary,Gender]  and so on.
```

Comment: If it's a file you are creating i suggest using [yaml](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) foramt it will be super easy to generate a simple and easy dict structure from the file.

Comment: @KobiK:Let me have a try at this.!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Data that you are iterating over is a file object. You can apply all the [itertools](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) tricks on it to reformat your data as a dictionary of list indexed with the key `ID`

So you start with a generator. This generator strips all non blank lines. Then you just iterate over this generator and create a dictionary using dictionary comprehension. Using [itertools.islice](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) advances your iterator to the extent, leaves the next item to be used as a key.

**Implementation**

```
from itertools import imap, islice
with open("data") as fin:
    data = (line for line in imap(str.strip, fin) if line)
    data = {line: list(islice(data, 0, 4)) for line in data}
```

**Output**

```
print data
{'ID2': ['Some name', 'Address', 'Salary', 'Gender'], 'ID1': ['Some name', 'Address', 'Salary', 'Gender']}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you already have them in a list, you need to create a dictionary using the [`grouper` recipe](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html):

```
from itertools import izip_longest

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)

ids = {i[0]: i[1:] for i in grouper(the_list,5)}
```

You'll end up with:

```
>>> the_list
['ID1', 'name1', 'address1', 'salary1', 'gender1', 'ID2', 'name2', 'address2',
'salary2', 'gender2']
>>> ids = {i[0]: i[1:] for i in grouper(the_list, 5)}
>>> ids
{'ID2': ('name2', 'address2', 'salary2', 'gender2'), 'ID1': ('name1', 'address1'
, 'salary1', 'gender1')}
```